# Detecting a selectInput value change to NULL in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

In the code below, I cannot detect `selectInput`'s value change to `NULL`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "var",
    label = "Select a variable:",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = T),
  textOutput("selected_var")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$var, {
    showNotification("var changed")
    output$selected_var <- renderPrint(paste0("selected var: ", input$var))
    if(is.null(input$var)) {                          # I want to be able to
      showNotification("var changed to null")         # detect this action
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If a user were to choose A then press the backspace to delete it, I want to be able to detect that action.

How would you detect the value of `input$var` changing to `NULL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `observeEvent` is set to ignore `NULL`. Adding `ignoreNULL = FALSE` to `observeEvent` will fix that. You may also wish to add `ignoreInit = TRUE` to stop the `observeEvent` from triggering on startup.

Here is the full code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput(inputId = "var", label = "Select a variable:", choices = c("A", "B", "C"), selected = NULL, multiple = T),

    textOutput("selected_var")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$var, {

        if(is.null(input$var)) {    

            showNotification("var changed to null")    

        }

    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's a shame this doesn't produce a warning or anything! If you didn't know to change your observers, a lot of validations would just fail silently thanks to this behavior...